# Remote server Returned an Error in Sharepoint 2013 provider hosted App

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I have created a sample provider hosted app refering the below article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx

Instead of hosting the Web app in iis express, I hosted it my IIS Server in my local  machine and I have deployed the App  to a Sharepoint server in another machine. I am using the credential of Site coll Admin and used client secret (requires a SharePoint farm connected to ACS) authentication

I used the same code as mentioned  in the article to fetch list and data.But I am getting the below error -

"The remote server returned an Error:(401) unauthorized". Access token is coming as empty

Any help would be greatful